# Can a react app be monitored for up time?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

We want to set up an uptime monitor for our single page React App which fetches videos from YouTube.  I have tried to set up an uptime monitor using several online services, such as uptime and monitis.  Both of these uptime monitoring sites search for specific HTML on a page.  however, they are failing.  My guess is because the html is rendered by the Single Page app.

How can we set up an uptime monitor therefore on our react app?

Comment: Why do you think the rendered html fail the uptime monitor? What do those monitor exactly work?

Answer (score 1):

The uptime monitors would fail, as the crawling bots wouldn't get the final HTML render unless you've set up SSR or workers to handle this.

There are probably a few methods you could use that would get the job done, the easiest of which is updating your server script with an interval to ping off.

There's a few good discussions around on the topic, but some are really not suitable:

[Heres one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709253/how-to-monitor-uptime-of-20-websites-ping-or-http-in-node-js-ror)

[Ping bot with slack](https://hackernoon.com/build-an-uptime-monitor-in-minutes-with-slack-standard-library-and-node-js-e7973d659849) which would be fun

If it's possible setting up some basic SSR would be handy too, any of the work would be done through your server script as opposed to the SPA itself

Comment: Hi there, I am not sure what you mean by "pdating your server script with an interval to ping off." or "unless you've set up SSR or workers to handle this."  Can you please explain?  Also, if you are on codementor.io, please let me know and perhaps I can hire you for a session